# Reproductive isolation causing evolution

Tags: evolution

My course book says about reproductive isolation that it does not allow the interbreeding among the individuals of different species. It also says that it is a cause of evolution.

How is this cause of evolution?

Comment: could you quote what the book says and tell us what book that is?

Answer (score 8):

Reproductive isolation isn't exactly a cause of evolution, but rather a cause of **speciation**. Reproductive isolation allows for two cohorts of one species to be reproductively separated. In this case, evolution via random mutation or mechanisms like genetic drift allows for the differentiation of the two groups, up to the point that the two cohorts and their respective gene pools have *evolved* to be completely different species.

Truly defining a species is still debatable (via the Biological species definition, Morphological, etc) but reproductive isolation is definitely a mechanism involved in speciation.